# Get java script variable in another html file?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, dom-events

I have lat,lng values in JavaScript which stores mouse clicked location. I stored them in window.lat and window.lat variables.what I want to do is append the lat,lng values to "http://maps.google.com/?q=lat,lng " and send as mail . I tried by creating hidden text field and accessing it using `document.getelement byid().value`.  But, how can I get the value from the hidden field from another HTML file that sends mail?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure what you mean by "how can i get the value from the hidden field from another HTML file that sends mail." Could you clarify your question a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your email script is `send_mail.php` and map is on `map.html`. When you want to send email, than from `map.html` (which has values lat and lng) you call mailing script with parameters `send_mail.php?lat=22.222&lng=55.555`. In PHP those values can be accessed via `$_GET['lat']` and `$_GET['lng']`;

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in the values you want as query parameters when you navigate the user to that other page.